# Error message while starting nodemanager in Hadoop under Windows 10 environment

Tags: hadoop, unsatisfiedlinkerror, nodemanager

In my Windows 10 environment, I installed Hadoop 2.10.1  While starting the nodemanager using .\start-yarn.cmd command, I am getting following error message.   The DataNode, ResourceManager and NameNode started properly though.

I need help in resolving this issue.

```
Error Log :-
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://github.com/apache/hadoop -r 1827467c9a56f133025f28557bfc2c562d78e816; compiled by 'centos' on 2020-09-14T13:17Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_292
************************************************************/
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: Node Manager health check script is not available or doesn't have execute permission, so not starting the node health script runner.
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$ContainerEventDispatcher
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$ApplicationEventDispatcher
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.event.LocalizationEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$LocalizationEventHandlerWrapper
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServicesEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainersLauncherEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainersLauncher
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.scheduler.ContainerSchedulerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.scheduler.ContainerScheduler
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerManagerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManagerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system started
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO nodemanager.DirectoryCollection: Disk Validator: yarn.nodemanager.disk-validator is loaded.
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO nodemanager.DirectoryCollection: Disk Validator: yarn.nodemanager.disk-validator is loaded.
22/08/16 10:27:20 ERROR nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode(NativeIO.java:521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:501)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:532)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.primitiveMkdir(FileSystem.java:1233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.mkdir(DelegateToFileSystem.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFs.mkdir(FilterFs.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:743)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.mkdir(FileContext.java:743)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:603)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createNonExistentDirs(DirectoryCollection.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.serviceInit(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:229)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeHealthCheckerService.serviceInit(NodeHealthCheckerService.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:878)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:946)
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics system...
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stopped.
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
22/08/16 10:27:20 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at DESKTOP-TFTO962/192.168.0.101
************************************************************/
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you are starting a fresh cluster, Hadoop 3 and Java 11 would be recommended.